# Gravatars/identicons with Mathematica

Tags: import, visualization, internet

The default avatar/[identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) is based on an MD5 hash of your e-mail address. With some e-mail providers (e.g., GMail) the address `gmailuser+foo@gmail.com` is still delivered to `gmailuser@gmail.com`, so this trick can be used to change the hash of your e-mail and thus get a different identicon, but there is no guarantee that it looks better than the original.

How can we semi-automate the search for your preferred identicon using Mathematica?

Comment: Of course the guaranteed way to get a pretty gravatar is to explicitly set it to a pretty picture. :-)

Comment: @celtschk Not everyone might want to sign up to Gravatar.

Comment: By the way, I think Leonid has one of the best generated Gravatars in the system and AFAIK it's for his real email address.

Comment: This is exactly how I picked my [autogenerated gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/147bba83ac4cea69be6ae54e7548b19e?s=512&d=identicon) (for those that remember) before I became the hypnotoad

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With this function a random integer is inserted in the e-mail address (gmailuser@gmail.com becomes gmailuser+randominteger@gmail.com) and then the hash value is computed. The hash value is used to get the corresponding identicon from the [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) website. This approach can address also some [privacy concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk).

```
generatePic[email_] := 
 Module[{emailparts, randN, input, inputhash, img},
  emailparts = StringSplit[email, "@"];
  randN = StringJoin["+", ToString[RandomInteger[99999]], "@"];
  input = emailparts[[1]] <> randN <> emailparts[[2]];
  inputhash = IntegerString[Hash[ToLowerCase[input], "MD5"], 16, 32];
  img = Import[
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" <> inputhash <> 
     "?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"];
  {img, input}
  ]
```

If we want to generate some identicons based on a specific e-mail address we just do this:

```
Grid[Table[generatePic["gmailuser@gmail.com"], {3}]]
```

[image: identicons]

Once we find an identicon we like, we just need to copy/paste the corresponding e-mail address into the e-mail field of the Stack Exchange profile.

**Update for Mathematica versions before 8**

It seems that older Mathematica versions include the enclosing quotes "" when it generates the hash, but there seems to be a [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/J19k50Fxhx0).

```
StringHash[string_String, type_: "MD5"] := 
 Module[{stream, file, hash}, stream = OpenWrite[];
  WriteString[stream, string];
  file = Close[stream];
  hash = FileHash[file, type];
  DeleteFile[file];
  hash]
```

And then:

```
generatePic[email_] := 
 Module[{emailparts, randN, input, inputhash, img}, 
  emailparts = StringSplit[email, "@"];
  randN = StringJoin["+", ToString[RandomInteger[99999]], "@"];
  input = emailparts[[1]] <> randN <> emailparts[[2]];
  inputhash = 
   IntegerString[StringHash[ToLowerCase[input], "MD5"], 16, 32];
  img = Import[
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" <> inputhash <> 
     "?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"];
  {img, input}]
```

Comment: I wish I had thought of this.  Nice work!

Comment: I've got a problem: **The avatar produced by your function doesn't match the one I get when I enter the email address in the profile here on StackExchange.**

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've tried several gmail addresses and they always matched. I'll try to see where the problem could be.

Comment: Then either it's my problem or v7 hash works differently.  I'll look again.

Comment: I tried another one and it also did not match.  Then I tried one from the picture in your answer and it *did*.  Would you please post the `inputhash` value you get for several addresses?

Comment: Alternatively: `input = StringInsert[#, "+" <> ToString[RandomInteger[99999]], StringPosition[#, "@"][[1, 1]]] & @ email`. If one wants slightly more generality, one can insert an arbitrary alphanumeric string of length `n` like so: `StringInsert[#, "+" <> StringJoin[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"] ~Join~ CharacterRange["0", "9"], n]], StringPosition[#, "@"][[1, 1]]] & @ "gmailuser@gmail.com"`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Here it works. For the first image in VLCs post I get `d9c48b644b8cc89bbcd07ec7a54dafc9` as hash. Btw, nice work VLC +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard On OsX you can get the hash by typing this in Terminal: `echo -n "gmailuser+10511@gmail.com" |md5`.

Comment: @halirutan please confirm the discrepancy.  For `IntegerString[Hash["gmailuser+10511@gmail.com", "MD5"], 16, 32]` I get `"cc270b8fbfb33469629c14e358183dd7"`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The discrepancy is there, on v8 I get `d9c48b644b8cc89bbcd07ec7a54dafc9`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The differences are also in the documentation for `Hash` in version [7](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Hash.html) and [8](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hash.html). Same examples, different outputs.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See update if it works on v7.

Comment: That works.  Go post an answer.

Comment: @J.M. Good suggestion for those who want to increase the search space. By replacing `RandomSample` with `RandomChoice` we can expand it even more.