# Finding largest Range in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

In a list of positive integers, I would like to find the largest `n` such that `Range[n]` is a subset of the list. So for example given `{1,2,3,5,7}` I want the answer to be `3`, while if the list is `{2,4,5}`, the answer should be `0`.

I can think of various algorithms that involve looping over the list, but there must be a better way. In my particular case, the lists are pretty small (well under 100 elements).

Comment: I'd say that in the second example the answer is `1`.

Comment: @Kuba No, I would like the answer to be zero, since `Range[2]` is not a subset of the given set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If speed is important, I think that this is a typical example in which compilation of a straightforward algorithm gives better results than making use of the advanced functions of Mathematica. Here is such a compiled function:

```
f= Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 1}}, Module[{result=0,counting=0},
  Do[ 
    If[n==counting+1,
      counting=n,
      If[counting>result, result=counting]; counting=If[n==1, 1, 0] ],
  {n, lst}];
  Max[{result, counting}]]]
```

On my computer, for a list of 10^6 positive integers, this function is more than 20 times faster than the splitting technique:

```
SeedRandom[42];
list=RandomInteger[{1,10},10^6];
Select[Split[list,#1+1==#2&],#[[1]]==1&]//Max // Timing
f[list] // Timing
fC[list] // Timing

(* {2.418016,5} *)
(* {0.109201,5} *)
(* {0.015600,5} *)
```

Here the function fC is identical to f, but compiled with the option CompilationTarget->"C". So when available, this gives another factor about 9.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be substantially faster.

```
extend[list_List, pos_List /; Length[pos] > 0, depth_Integer] := 
 extend[list, 
  pos[[Flatten[
      Position[list[[DeleteCases[Flatten[pos], Length[list]] + 1]], 
       depth + 1]]]] + 1, depth + 1]

extend[list_List, {}, depth_Integer] := depth - 1

extend[list, Position[list, 1], 1]
```

Also, using `Max` gives negative infinity when there is no element 1 in the list.

This seems analogous to Boyer-Moore.  Therefore, a further improvement would be to extend the first matching substring as much as possible (let's say the length of the substring is `n`), and then at the second matching substring check to see if it could be longer (by checking the element `n` positions after the start of the second matching substring), etc.

Comment: Nice idea! But there seems to be some bugs. Your code cancelled with `SeedRandom[42]; list = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, 100]; extend[list,  Position[list, 1], 1]`. Any idea if what's happening?

Comment: Should have been `Drop[Flatten[pos] + 1, -1]` (since the last element is not extensible).  Fixed that, but I still get a different answer than the code based on `Split` on a few test cases. I will look into that.

Comment: This needs to be reworked a little more, but the idea is right.  The problem is that the `Position`s in the sublist need to be translated back to their position in the original list (when searching for the higher elements).

Comment: OK, I think that should do it.  The `Drop[..,-1]` had to be changed to `DeleteCases[..,Length[list]]` becase we only want to delete the last of the matches with the value we are currently searching if it is the last element in the list.  And the `pos[[some_fun[pos]]]` allows us to map positions in the sublist back to positions in the original list.  Over a bunch of random examples, the output of the above matches the code based on `Split` above.

Comment: @xcah I have been notified of a pending edit to [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56729/121).  Is the item you added different from the very first item in the list, addressed in [(13529)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13529/121)?

Comment: Yes, the changed between 9 and 10.  And there is no documentation of how to compute the function that was present in 9 (this forced me to recompute a bunch of magic data).  On 10, `Hash["abcde"]` yields 3335709116491347743.  On 9, the same yields 8840055571401358647.  As a result, I highly recommend _never_ using Hash without specifying the algorithm.

Comment: @xcah Thanks for your contribution.  I too cannot find a way to generate the old value.

Comment: @xcah Would you please post a question asking for a way to generate the legacy hash value?  I would like to know myself but since you brought the problem to my attention I think the question should come from you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Done, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68954/can-one-generate-the-default-output-of-hashexpr-from-mathematica-9-in-mat).

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1 = Module[{i = 1}, While[SequencePosition[#, Range[i], 1] =!= {}, i++]; i-1]&;
f2 = Module[{i = 0}, While[SequencePosition[#, Range[++i], 1] =!= {}]; i-1]&;

f1 /@ {{1, 2, 3, 5, 7}, {3, 2, 1, 5, 7}, {3, 2, 7, 5}}
```

> {3, 1, 0}

```
f2 /@ {{1, 2, 3, 5, 7}, {3, 2, 1, 5, 7}, {3, 2, 7, 5}}
```

> {3, 1, 0}

**Timings:**

Both `f1` and `f2` are faster than all the methods (except possibly `fC` in Fred Simon's answer which I cannot use because I don't have a C compiler installed) posted so far.

```
SeedRandom[42];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10^6];
rsel = Max @ Select[Split[list,#1+1==#2&],#[[1]]==1&] // Timing; (* belisarius *)
rext = extend[list, Position[list, 1], 1] // Timing; (* xcah *)
rf = f[list] // Timing; (* fred simons *)
rf1 = f1[list] //Timing;

Grid[{{"Select", "extend", "f", "f1"}, {rsel, rext, rf, rf1}}, Dividers->All]// TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{Select} & \text{extend} & f & \text{f1} & \text{f2} \\
> \hline
>  \{1.453,5\} & \{0.137,5\} & \{0.039,5\} & \{0.008,5\} & \{0.008,5\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

With `list = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, 10^6];`

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{Select} & \text{extend} & f & \text{f1} & \text{f2} \\
> \hline
>  \{1.68,2\} & \{0.047,2\} & \{0.039,2\} & \{0.012,2\} & \{0.011,2\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[42];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 7}, 1000];
Select[Split[list, #1 + 1 == #2 &], #[[1]] == 1 &] // Max
(* 3*)
```

Comment: Nice. Is the `Length /@` necessary? Doesn't `Max[{{1,2,3}}]` yield `3`?

Comment: @rogerl That's right. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Please, run your code with the list `{2,4,5}`.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9};

MaximalBy[Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &], Length]
```

{{4, 5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8, 9}}

```
MaximalBy[Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &], Length, 1]
```

{{4, 5, 6, 7}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `SequenceCases` and [ConsecutiveQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140472/ordered-subsequences-of-consecutive-integers):

```
ConsecutiveQ = Most[#] == Rest[#] - 1 &;(*By Kuba*)

f = Max@Map[Length@If[Range[Last@#] === #, #, {}] &, 
    Cases[Subsequences[#, {1, Length[#], 1}], _?ConsecutiveQ]] &;

l1 = {4, 2, 5};
l2 = {2, 4, 5};
l3 = {3, 2, 7, 5};
l4 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7};
l5 = {3, 2, 1, 5, 7};
l6 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9};(*By Eldo*)

f /@ {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6}

(*{0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3}*)
```