# How to differentiate formally?

Tags: variable-definitions, attributes, summation

I have been wrapping my head around this for a while now and I have not found a solution so far. I want to work with an arbitrary number of variables in *Mathematica* and use some built in functions. To make things more specific for starters I want to do the following. Define a sum with $n$ summands each containing a new variable `x[i]` (in the $i$-th summand):

```
sum[n_] = Sum[i x[i], {i, 1, n}]
```

Then I want to differentiate the expression with respect to some `x[i]` like:

```
D[sum[n], x[2]]
```

*Mathematica* returns $0$ instead of $2$. However if I supply a specific $n$ like:

```
D[sum[2], x[2]]
```

everything works fine. I thought about using `Assumption` for $n$, but with no success so far. How can I do that right?

Comment: Evaluating `D[sum[n], x[2]]` is essentially the same as evaluating `D[Sum[n, y], x[2]]`, where `y` is value-free, which is nothing `D` recognizes as depending on `x[2]`.

Comment: This question is closely related to and might even be considered a duplicate of [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13146/generating-a-vector-of-dummy-variables)

Comment: Extending Mathematica to allow sums of symbolic length really would require extended it to allow lists of symbolic length; only then could one properly worry about differentiating such objects. But how to make a robust, general design for such an extension is hardly obvious and raises all sorts of issues, e.g.: Should `Infinity` to an acceptable value for `n`? What would the effect be upon processing speed for specific-length objects?

Comment: I've changed your title to something more specific. please change it to something else if you think it's better

Comment: For formal differentiation, what I've noticed is if it's in a tuxedo it's probably a guy, and if it's in a gown it's usually a gal. But this is only a rough guideline, and anyway times have changed.

Comment: This question is not related to generating a given amount of variables to use later on. The calculation should be without the need to specify a specific amount. The only prior should be that the number of variables is limited.

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry for the newbie question, but how exactly is `D[sum[n], x[2]]` the same thing as `D[Sum[n, y], x[2]]`? In particular, `Sum[n,y] = ny` since it sums n y times but `sum[n] = ` $\sum^{n}_{i=1} i x[i]$ (you can check it on a notebook on mathematica).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here is the simplest answer:

```
sum[n_] := Sum[i x[i], {i, 1, n}]

x /: D[x[i_], x[j_], NonConstants -> {x}] := 
 KroneckerDelta[i, j]

D[sum[n], x[2], NonConstants -> x]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  2 & n>1 \\
>  1-n & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

The trick here is the use of the `NonConstants` option of the derivative operator. This then has to be combined with a definition stating that the `x[i]` are independent variables for the purposes of this differentiation (hence the `KroneckerDelta` on the second line).

**Edit: more discussion**

And here is another cool result, completely symbolic:

```
Assuming[m ∈ Integers, D[sum[n], x[m], NonConstants -> x]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  m & m\geq 1 \\
>  0 & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)-\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  m & m>2\land m\geq n+1 \\
>  n+1 & m=2\land n=1 \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

This isn't easy to absorb, but it works if you check it with specific examples by doing

```
condition = %;

Simplify[condition /. m -> 10]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  10 & n>9 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

In summary, it's worth pointing out that a lot of symbolic differentiation tasks can be achieved by using *either* [`NonConstants`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonConstants.html?q=NonConstants&lang=en) specifications in [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/D.html) or conversely using [`Constants`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Constants.html?q=Constants&lang=en) specifications in [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dt.html).

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that when doing this with more than one variable (say $x$ and $y$), it is necessary to have them `Sort`ed in the NonConstants rule for the UpValue of the variables, otherwise it won't find a match when trying to evaluate `D` (and leave it unevaluated).

Comment: sorry if this a super newbie question, but why does it say $1-n$ for...true? :/ What does that condition even mean?

Comment: @Pinocchio `True` is the entry that humans would call "otherwise" - it's the default alternative if none of the above holds.

Comment: @Jens I see what true means now (weird, the programmer could have just said otherwise in a print statement...). But, how is the derivative wrt `x[2]` be `1 - n` for `n < 1`? for `n<1` the sum doesn't even exist...so wouldn't technically it be the derivative of a non-existent sum (so zero), so the derivative of zero is zero? Or am I completely off?

Comment: @Pinocchio No, the only other case in that sum is `n=1`.

Comment: @Jens if `n=1` then $\sum_i i x_i = 1 x_1$ and `n-1 = 0`. Isn't that still sort of a bizarre ting to do if we are taking the derivative with respect to `x[2]`? Sorry, I am just trying to understand why the output is the way it is. Currently, it still doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: @Pinocchio Of course it looks weird, but nonetheless it's a true statement because the derivative is taken with respect to a variable that (for `n=1`) doesn't occur in the sum. Therefore its value would be `1-n==0`. What makes it a little confusing is that the output is not in the most simplified form because `n` still appears even though it can only have one value in that last line. Still, it's correct.

Comment: @Jens sorry for taking this discussion further, I am genuinely curious about this and there's something that still "bothers me". In particular, why didn't mathematica return $1 - n + n^2 - n^3 + n^4 - n^ 5 $ that is also zero...and you might ask me, why did I choose that weird equation and my answer is...Its random. But is mathematica expression random? Or was there a reason it chose $1 - n$ and not (any) other expression that involves n and is zero (in this special case `n=1`). Do you know what I mean? I wish I knew. If I did I wouldn't have extended this discussion :p

Answer (score 23):

I did some computation of formal derivatives a while back which might be of interest in this context (though keep in mind that this is anything but bullet proof! it does work for the cases I bothered to check though).

```
Clear[a]; Format[a[k_]] = Subscript[a, k]
```

Let us say we have an objective function which is formally a function of 
the vector `a[i]`

```
Q = Sum[Log[Sum[a[r] Subscript[B, r][Subscript[x, i]], {r, 1, p}]/
    Sum[a[r] , {r, 1, p}]], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let us define a couple of rules for formal differentiation as follows

```
Clear[d];
d[Log[x_], a[k_]] := 1/x d[x, a[k]]
d[Sum[x_, y__], a[k_]] := Sum[d[x, a[k]], y]
d[ a[k_] b_., a[k_]] := b /; FreeQ[b, a]
d[ a[q_] b_., a[k_]] := b Subscript[δ, k, q] /; FreeQ[b, a]
d[ c_  b_, a[k_]] := d[c, a[k]] b + d[b, a[k]] c
d[ b_ +  c_, a[k_]] := d[c, a[k]] + d[b, a[k]]
d[Subscript[δ, r_, q_], a[k_]] := 0
d[x_, a[k_]] := 0 /; FreeQ[x, a]
 d[G_^n_, a[k_]] := n G^(n - 1) d[G , a[k]] /; ! FreeQ[G, a]
 d[Exp[G_], a[q_]] := Exp[G] d[G , a[q]] /; ! FreeQ[G, a]

Unprotect[Sum]; Attributes[Sum] = {ReadProtected};Protect[Sum];
```

And a rule to deal with Kroneckers

```
ds = {Sum[a_ + b_, {s_, 1, p_}] :> Sum[a, {s, 1, p}] + Sum[b, {s, 1, p}],
      Sum[ y_ Subscript[δ, r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> (y /. s -> r),
  Sum[ y_ Subscript[δ, s_, r_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> (y /. s -> r),
  Sum[ Subscript[δ, s_, r_], {r_, 1, p_}] :> 1,
  Sum[δ[i_, k_] δ[j_, k_] y_. , {k_, n_}] -> δ[i, j] (y /. k -> i),
  Sum[a_ b_, {r_, 1, p_}] :> a Sum[b, {r, 1, p}] /; NumberQ[a],
  Sum[a__, {r_, 1, p_}] :>  Sum[Simplify[a], {r, 1, p}] }
```

Then, for instance, the gradient of `Q` with respect to one of the `a[k]` reads

```
grad = d[Q, a[k]]  /. ds // Simplify;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similarly the tensor of second derivatives w.r.t. `a[k]` and `a[s]` is given by

```
hess = d[d[Q, a[k]], a[s]] /. ds // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a less trivial example let us consider the 4th order derivatives of `Q`

```
 d[d[d[d[Q, a[k]], a[s]], a[m]], a[t]]; /. ds // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the problem at hand we check easily that

```
 Q = Sum[r a[r] , {r, 1, p}];

 grad = d[Q, a[k]] // Simplify;
 grad //. ds
```

returns `k` as it should

**EDIT**

This process can be made a bit more general, say, on this Objective function

```
  Q = 1/2 Sum[(Sum[a[r] Subscript[B, r, i][a[q]], {r, 1, p}] - 
      Subscript[y, i])^2, {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which depends non linearly on `a[k]` via `B`.

All we need is to add a new rule for `d`

```
d[H_[a[q_]], 
  a[k_]] := (D[H[x] , x] /. x -> a[k] ) Subscript[δ, k, q]
```

Now we readily have

```
grad = d[Q, a[k]] // Simplify;
hess = d[d[Q, a[k]], a[s]];

grad //. ds
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
hess /. ds // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a other example, let us look at a parametrized  entropy distance,

```
 Q = -Sum[(Sum[a[r] Subscript[B, r, i], {r, 1, p}]/
  Subscript[y, i]) Log[(Sum[a[r] Subscript[B, r, i], {r, 1, p}]/
   Subscript[y, i])], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

we can compute its Hessian while mapping twice the sum rule

```
 Map[# /. ds &, d[d[Q, a[k]], a[s]] /. ds]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a final example, consider a Poisson likelihood

```
 Q = Sum[Log[Exp[-a[k]] a[k]^Subscript[y, k]/Subscript[y, k]!], {k, 1, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

so that

```
 grad = d[Q, a[k]] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
  hess =d[d[Q, a[k]], a[s]]  /. ds // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course these algebraic rules are not bullet proof but illustrate nicely the way mathematica handles new grammar.

Comment: @Nasser have you seen [this?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes)

Comment: unfortunately, i can not replicate these results in Mathematica 10.2. I would be appreciative if someone could try to reproduce this and/or suggest edits.

Comment: I also cannot replicate these results using Mathematica 11

Comment: I have added one rule to solve the pb on the last two example. It now works for Mathematica 10.3.

Answer (score 9):

Starting in M11.1, this works:

```
sum[n_] = Sum[i x[i],{i,1,n}];

D[sum[n],x[2]] //InputForm
```

> Piecewise[{{2, n >= 2}}, 0]

Comment: I've got M11, and I still get a result of 0.

Comment: Works for me in Mathematica 11.1.1 on MacOS Sierra.

Comment: @clr66 I should have said starting in M11.1.

Comment: Finally managed to upgrade to M11.1.1 and attempted the following:
`Assuming[{1<=j<=n,Element[j,Integers]},D[Sum[i f[i],{i,1,n}],f[j]]]`

`(* j *)`

So far, so good.  However, I also get the following:
`Assuming[{1<=j<=n,Element[j,Integers]},D[Sum[i g[f[i]],{i,1,n}],f[j]]]`

`(* Sum[i*KroneckerDelta[i, j]*Derivative[1][g][f[i]], {i, 1, n}] *)`

This answer is technically correct, although it would be nice to get a clean result of
`j g'[f[j]]`
Is there a way to get the KroneckerDelta to return this result?

Answer (score 6):

One solution might be ...

**Method 1.**

Define some variables:

```
x = Table[Unique[], {5}];
```

Form the inner product and differentiate:

```
D[Inner[Times, x, Range@Length@x], x[[2]]]
```

> 2

Or if you prefer it in a functional form:

```
sum[n_] := Inner[Times, x[[1 ;; n]], Range@n] /; ( Length@x >= n)

D[sum[4], x[[3]]]
```

> 3

**Method 2.**

You could take a different approach, but you need to be aware that it leaks variables of the form `{x1,x2,x3,...}` out into the general context:

```
sum[n_] := Inner[Times, Symbol["x" <> ToString@#] & /@ Range@n, Range@n] 

sum[5]
```

> x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 + 4 x4 + 5 x5

```
D[sum3[4], x3]
```

> 3

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to avoid. The exact amount of variables should not have to be specified.

Answer (score 4):

I like image_doctor's solution better, but how about using `Array` and looking for the position using that index each time? Like this:

```
xx = Array[x, 10, 1];
sum[n_] := Times[List @@ xx , Range[10]]

sum[n]
(* {x[1], 2 x[2], 3 x[3], 4 x[4], 5 x[5], 6 x[6], 7 x[7], 8 x[8], 9 x[9], 10 x[10]} *)
```

Now

```
sum[n_] := Times[List @@ xx^4, Range[10]]
D[sum[n], xx[[5]]][[5]]
(*  20 x[5]^3 *)
```

and

```
sum[n_] := Times[List @@ xx, Range[10]]
D[sum[n], xx[[2]]][[2]]

(* 2 *)
```

It is kinda clumsy though. The problem, of course, is that one can't treat

[image]

as a single variable as we do on paper. P.S., I tried to see if one can do this in Maple and could not do it directly as you wanted. Had to do a hack as above. (But I do not know Maple much, though.)

Comment: Nasser, if it matters to you, your "gravatar" is changing along with your I.P. address.  You can make it a fixed one by entering an email address in your profile.  This email is only visible to moderators and furthermore it doesn't need to be a real one anyway.  Also see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13525/121

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to use the fact that Mathematica can easily take the derivative of an actual sum, but has problems with the symbolic one. In order to take the derivative on `j`-th term of a sum, we extract from the sum few terms centered around `j`. The number of extracted terms is equal to `2*dj+1`. There is one drawback of this solution that you can always differentiate on `j`-th term. This method works with subscripted variables as well.

```
s1 = Sum[p[k]*a[k + 1] + p[k + 1]*a[k], {k, 1, nn}];
derivSum[s0_, xj_, dj_] := Block[{k, j}, D[Sum[s0[[1]], {k, j - dj, j + dj}], xj]];
derivSum[s1, p[j], 4]
(* a[-1+j]+a[1+j] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"  *)

sum[n_] = Sum[i x[i], {i, 1, n}];

Assuming[Element[{n, m}, Integers] && n >= m >= 1, D[sum[n], x[m]]]

(*  m  *)

Assuming[Element[{n, m}, Integers] && n >= 1 && m >= 1, 
 D[sum[n], x[m]] // Simplify]
```

[image]