# How to get (fg)' = f'g + g'f?

Tags: symbolic

I am new to Mathematica so the my questions might be pretty much at the pupil's level.

If I want to use differentiation to derive:

```
    (fg)' = f'g + g'f
```

How can I keep empty symbol `f, g` from been evaluated for derivative and get 0? For example if I use

```
    D[f g, x]
```

I immediately get 0 result. I guess it might be related to **hold**, but couldn't find out the correct way to get it work.

Comment: Try `Dt[f g, x]`.

Comment: Or perhaps, `D[f[x] g[x], x]`.

Comment: Or try `D[f[x] g[x], x]`

Comment: Michael wins this round

Comment: Closely related: [how to differentiate formally](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16375/245)

Answer (score 8):

Some alternatives (picked from the comments):

```
D[f[x] g[x], x]

Dt[f g, x]

f[#] g[#] &'
```

Comment: Great it is solved!

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of something like `f[#] g[#] &'`.