# Deriving least-squares equations in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, summation

I define $Y = a + b*x + e$, and I want to find values for $a,b,$ by least squares, so I minimize $RSS = sum((Y_i - a - b*x_i)^2)$

I then take derivatives, ${d RSS \over da} = 0$ and ${d RSS \over db} = 0$ and solve. Now if I put these formulas into *Mathematica*,

```
f2[a_, b_, y_, x_, n_] = Sum[(y[i] - a - b*x[i])^2, {i, n}] 

Solve[{D[f2[a, b, y, x, n], {a}] == 0, D[f2[a, b, y, x, n], {b}] == 0}, {a, b}]
```

I get the following error.

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

The derivatives work, but *Mathematica* doesn't know how to expand out the summations.

Any thoughts? I've tried `Expand`, `Sum`, `Distribute` (as suggested in some different expanding `Sum` questions).

I've also seen some thoughts on how to define *Mathematica* rules for summations (anyone have those?).

Comment: Probably related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16378/193

Comment: thanks belisarius, that's what i needed

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to fix things. I've set values for `x` and `y` in arrays (rather than having them be undefined values of functions):

```
n = 10;
x = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, n];
y = 3 x + RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, n]; 
f2[a_, b_, y_, x_, n_] = Sum[(y[[i]] - a - b*x[[i]])^2, {i, n}];
Solve[{D[f2[a, b, y, x, n], {a}] == 0, D[f2[a, b, y, x, n], {b}] == 0}, {a, b}]

{{a -> -(103/956), b -> 5699/1912}}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I was looking for a numerical way and it looks like belisarius' comment was what I needed