# How to minimize the sum of squares of deviations from the mean?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I am trying to minimize the sum of squares of a deviation from the mean applying the following:

```
Minimize[Sum[(Subscript[x, i] - μ)^2, {i, 0, n}], x]
```

It returns the expression, but I was expecting it to return an answer similar to the one below

```
Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 0, n}]/n
```

which is the sample mean.

Is this kind of minimization possible in *Mathematica*?

Comment: You can do this if you giver an explicit value for `n` and Minimize the variable `\[Mu]` (`x` is not a variable in your formulation).

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan..I tried the following `Minimize[Sum[(Subscript[x, i] - \[Mu])^2, {i, 0, 10}], \[Mu]]` and it works great. Thanks again

Comment: On a similar note how would you minimize the function with weights added `Minimize[Sum[
  Subscript[w, i]*(Subscript[x, i] - \[Mu])^2, {i, 0, 1}], \[Mu]]`..so the answer is `(Subscript[w, 0] Subscript[x, 0] + 
   Subscript[w, 1] Subscript[x, 1])/(Subscript[w, 1] + Subscript[w, 2]
   )` and not the various values it gives

Comment: you may want to look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16378/1089

Comment: Thanks but it specifies the rules of differentiation to solve a much more complex problem. I am trying to minimize a simple wieghted sum of deviation from the mean so that the solution returns the weighted average. Not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

> You can do this if you giver an explicit value for n and Minimize the variable μ (x is not a variable in your formulation).
>
> – Daniel Lichtblau Jun 2 '14 at 20:56

```
Minimize[Sum[(Subscript[x, i] - μ)^2, {i, 0, 10}], μ]
```

[image]