# Derivative of an expression containing a symbolic sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

Is there a general pattern for working with symbolic sums in *Mathematica*?

For example here's a derivative I want to compute:

```
D[Exp[Subscript[λ, α] x]/Sum[Exp[Subscript[λ, β] x],{β, 1, k}], Subscript[λ, α]]
```

The derivative is with respect to a parameter `Subscript[λ, α]`, and it appears explicitly in the numerator, and implicitly in the denominator due to the sum. *Mathematica* differentiates the numerator where the parameter is explicitly present, but it misses the fact that the sum over the denominator contains an instance of `Subscript[λ, α]`.

I can hack a solution to this since without loss of generality I could assume that the subscript `α` takes the value 1 and separate that term from the symbolic sum in the denominator.

But is there a way to represent the sum in the denominator so that *Mathematica* understands that `Subscript[λ, α]` is contained in the set `Subscript[λ, β]`?

Comment: `appears explicitly in the numerator, and implicitly in the denominator due to the sum` I do not see it. The denominator has no `Subscript[\[Lambda], \[Alpha]]` in it at all. The sum is over beta, not alpha. Here is screen shot of your expression ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j2s9r.png)

Comment: The idea is that `\[Alpha]` is a non-negative integer in `[1,k]`, so there is going to be a term in the series in the denominator where `\[Alpha]=\[Beta]`.

Comment: `so there is going to be a term in the series in the denominator where \[Alpha]=\[Beta]` This I do not understand at all. You are doing symbolic differentiation?  How is Mathematica supposed to know that Alpha and Beta are the same symbol at one point?

Comment: Well that's my question exactly. As I pointed out in my question I could explicitly set `\[Alpha]` to 1 for example and explicitly code the corresponding term in the denominator and get the right answer. But I'm wondering if there's some way to state the assumption that `\[Alpha]` is a non-negative integer that is in the same range as the index for the sum which would force Mathematica to differentiate the denominator.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [how to differentiate formally](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16375/245). You only have to get rid of the `Subscript`s as variable names because they bury the meaning of the actual labels $\alpha$ and $\beta$ too deeply. Replace `Subscript[lambda][alpha]` by `lambda[alpha]` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get the expression yo simplify to the fullest extent, one could make the additional assumption that the label $\alpha$ always falls within the range of the summation whose index is $\beta$. To do this, we have to add some rules which are easier to write if the starting expression is brought into a slightly different form:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \lambda (\alpha )}\frac{\exp
   (\lambda (\alpha ) x)}{\sum _{\beta } \exp (\lambda
   (\beta ) x)}$$

Here I omitted the summation indices because I want to ignore them anyway (equivalent to the assumption stated above). I also eliminated the subscripts because they are never a good idea as a method of indexing variable names.

Now we're ready to apply the method outlined in [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16390/245), adding one more assumption (again to implement the assumption stated above) - which is that sums should be killed provided that they contain a Kronecker delta in which the summation index appears. I chose the simplest route here and associated this rule with the symbol `β` so that this brute-force simplification only applies when you choose `β` as the summation variable. That way, you could still allow similar sums where you do *not* wish to make the assumption that $\alpha$ is in the summation range. Those would then use a summation index different from `β` and not get simplified.

```
λ /: 
 D[λ[i_], λ[j_], NonConstants -> {λ}] := 
 KroneckerDelta[i, j]

β /: Sum[KroneckerDelta[α_, β] rest___, β] :=
  Times[rest] /. β :> α

D[Exp[λ[α] x]/
  Sum[Exp[λ[β] x], β], λ[α], 
 NonConstants -> {λ}]
```

> $$\frac{x e^{x \lambda (\alpha )}}{\sum _{\beta } e^{x
>    \lambda (\beta )}}-\frac{x e^{2 x \lambda (\alpha
>    )}}{\left(\sum _{\beta } e^{x \lambda (\beta
>    )}\right){}^2}$$

This is the answer you are probably looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about the flexibility of evaluation in Mathematica. If you don't mind me asking a follow up question, can you expand on what the TagSetDelayed rule for `\[Beta]` is doing? My understanding (which must be wrong) is that when evaluating the `Sum` expression in the denominator Mathematica encounters the expression `\[Beta]` and then it trys to apply the rule you defined. But the lhs of the definition in your rule has `KroneckerDelta` and the `Sum` in the denominator doesn't so how does the match happen?

Comment: Actually this is what I get when I run your code: $$-\frac{e^{x \lambda [\alpha ]} D\left[\sum _{\beta } e^{x \lambda [\beta ]},\lambda [\alpha ],\text{NonConstants}\to \{\lambda \}\right]}{\left(\sum _{\beta } e^{x \lambda [\beta ]}\right){}^2}+\frac{e^{x \lambda [\alpha ]} x}{\sum _{\beta } e^{x \lambda [\beta ]}}$$ It has the right structure, but there's an unevaluated derivative still.

Comment: @StripesPlaid Indeed, the last simplification works in *Mathematica* version 10.0.1, but not in version 8. I'm guessing you're using an older version. The `TagSetDelayed` rule for $\beta$ only gets applied in  the 10.0.1 version after the derivative has been done under the sum. Then what the rule says is that whenever $\beta$ appears as the summation index without any additional range specification, *and* there is a Kronecker delta involving $\beta$, you're supposed to reduce the sum to the `rest` multiplying the delta.

Comment: I see, so the `TagSetDelayed` rule for $\lambda$ results in what I'm seeing, and then in Mathematica 10 the remaining derivative is carried out under the sum and leaves a `KroneckerDelta` which triggers the evaluation of the rule for $\beta$. Am I getting that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.