# Doing vector calculus with element-wise defined formulas and arbitrary-sized vectors

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, vector

Currently I am trying to make *Mathematica* handle vector expressions defined element-wise. For example,

[image]

But I can find no way to do this. Every way I tried requires a fixed-sized vector and returns a fixed sized vector rather than a formula for elements.

[image: x and y]

Evaluating `y[{1, 2, 3}]` works but `y[x]` doesn't work.

I'm new to *Mathematica*, but I believe there's an elegant way to do this :)

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: @Louis thank you for your comments. It helped a lot. In fact I'm not completely new to stackexchange. I often answer and ask on stackoverflow.com. I think it won't take long time to be used to it. :D

Comment: Looks exactly like what I [answered here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63530/245). So it's probably a duplicate of [how to differentiate formally](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16375/245)

Comment: I found few things made me in trouble. Presense of /: := operator, not knowing KroneckerDelta, NonConstants optional of D, Assuming, ... I'm continuing trial.