# Formal Differentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

I'm trying to formally differentiate an expression. (I am aware of [how to differentiate formally?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/how-to-differentiate-formally/16390#16390), but am unable to generalize the idea)

For example:

```
tmp1 = Sum[Product[MyVal[i, j]^(1/n), {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]
```

I would like to take the derivative with respect to some i in 1...n and j in 1...n . I thought I could specify something like

```
MyVal /: D[MyVal[i_, j_], MyVal[k_, l_], NonConstants -> {MyVal}] :=
     KroneckerDelta[i, k]*KroneckerDelta[j, l]
```

Then take the derivative

```
D[tmp1, MyVal[i, j]]
```

But this turns out not to work as expected. Any help in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think formal differentiation of `Product` only works if you specify a numerical value for the limit `n`:

For example,

```
tmp = With[{n = 3},
   Sum[Product[MyVal[i, j]^(1/n), {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]];

FullSimplify[D[tmp, MyVal[i1, j1], NonConstants -> {MyVal}]]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Ah, so it does have some logic for Product, but won't go far enough. I guess I'll have to do some of this by hand still!

Comment: Since nothing else has come along, I'll go ahead and accept this.