# How can I find the formal derivative of a polynomial w.r.t. to its coefficients

Tags: symbolic, polynomials

I want to define a function $f(x)$ as in

$\quad \quad  f(x) = \sum^{n}_{i=0} c_i x^i$

as a symbolic expression. Then I'd like to do operations on it. For example, take derivatives of it with respect to any variable or collection of variables. Is there a concise way to do this, so that I get the results in symbolic form?

Again, for example, if I would like to get $ x^i$ from evaluating $ \frac{d f(x)}{dc_i}$.

Comment: Is $n$ a fixed number, or do you want to leave it symbolic? If $n$ is symbolic, then have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16375)?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I wasn't really planning to take derivatives with respect n, so fixed would be ok, for a specific $f(x)$. I wish I knew more about mathematica to know how that matters/makes a difference. I am more concerned to take derivatives wrt to $c_i$ and $x^i$.

Comment: Then, it's easy to just do `D[Sum[C[k] x^k, {k, 0, 5}], x]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. doesn't quite work as the example I gave. If I do D[Sum[C[k] x^k, {k, 0, 5}], C[k]] it returns zeros, should return $x^k$. But its definitively a good start! :D

Comment: That's the "leave it symbolic" case in my previous comment; in which case, I already pointed you to an applicable thread.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I will take a look at the thread then. Thanks for the help Guess who it is...miley cyrus? :p

Comment: That's because there is no `C[k]` to differentiate against; only `C[0]`, `C[1]`, … and heavens, I do not jut out my posterior like that in public!

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Time to change your display name. How about: "You all know who it is"?

Comment: @m_goldberg so he is Miley?