# How to express and take symbolic derivative of expression with finite sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the expression:

$$
p_i = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} e^{x_j}}
$$

which I defined with the following Mathematica code:

```
Subscript[p, i] = E^Subscript[x, i] / Sum[E^Subscript[x, j], {j, 1, n}]
```

I tried to take the derivative with respect to an $x_i$:

```
D[Subscript[p, i], Subscript[x,i]]
```

but, I just get the expression back as the result:

$$
\frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} e^{x_j}}
$$

Obviously, I am doing something wrong. How should I go about working with this type of expression?

Comment: Is it safe to say `1<i<n`?

Comment: Or rather, is it expected? If that's not true, then the result you get makes sense since the denominator may not necessarily be a function of `Subscript[x,i]`.

Comment: May be [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16378/1089) can help?

Comment: @It'sPronouncedOiler Yes, `1<=i<=n`. Is there some way I need to communicate that information to the `D` function?

Comment: @RandomBits what's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Following [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16378/1089),
if we define a couple of rules for formal differentiation.

```
Clear[d];
d[Log[x_], a[k_]] := 1/x d[x, a[k]]
d[Sum[x_, y__], a[k_]] := Sum[d[x, a[k]], y]
d[a[k_] b_., a[k_]] := b /; FreeQ[b, a]
d[a[q_] b_., a[k_]] := b Subscript[δ, k, q] /; FreeQ[b, a]
d[c_ b_, a[k_]] := d[c, a[k]] b + d[b, a[k]] c
d[b_ + c_, a[k_]] := d[c, a[k]] + d[b, a[k]]
d[Subscript[δ, r_, q_], a[k_]] := 0
d[x_, a[k_]] := 0 /; FreeQ[x, a]
d[G_^n_, a[k_]] := n G^(n - 1) d[G, a[k]] /; ! FreeQ[G, a]
d[Exp[G_], a[q_]] := Exp[G] d[G, a[q]] /; ! FreeQ[G, a]
```

and some simplification rules

```
ds = {Sum[a_ + b_, {s_, 1, p_}] :> 
    Sum[a, {s, 1, p}] + Sum[b, {s, 1, p}], 
   Sum[y_ Subscript[δ, r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> (y /. s -> r), 
   Sum[y_ Subscript[δ, s_, r_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> (y /. s -> r), 
   Sum[Subscript[δ, s_, r_], {r_, 1, p_}] :> 1, 
   Sum[δ[i_, k_] δ[j_, k_] y_., {k_, n_}] -> δ[i,
       j] (y /. k -> i), 
   Sum[a_ b_, {r_, 1, p_}] :> a Sum[b, {r, 1, p}] /; NumberQ[a]};


 Clear[a]; Format[a[k_]] = Subscript[a, k]
```

Then considering

```
    Q = Exp[a[i]]/Sum[Exp[a[j]], {j, 1, n}]; Q /. a -> x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

we have for instance

```
 grad = d[Q, a[p]] //. ds /. a -> x // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is fairly general (though not fully bullet proof): for instance

```
Q = Exp[2 a[i] a[k]]/Sum[Exp[a[j]], {j, 1, n}]^4; Q /. a -> x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  grad = d[Q, a[p]] //. ds; grad /. a -> x // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  hess = d[grad, a[q]] //. ds /. a -> x // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was hoping to be able to get the result without explicitly adding all of the derivative and simplification rules. After following the link in your answer, I found that I could show Mathematica the relationship I intended between `x[i]` and `x[j]` with the following code: `x /: D[x[i],x[j],NonConstants -> {x}] = KroneckerDelta[i,j]`.

Comment: I also found the user of format in your answer (`Format[a[k_]] = Subscript[a, k]`) very useful.

Answer (score 6):

In M11.1+ derivatives of sums behave the way you requested:

```
Assuming[
    i ∈ Integers && 1<=i<=n,
    Simplify @ D[Subscript[p,i], Subscript[x,i]]
] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{e^{x_i} \left(\sum _{j=1}^n e^{x_j}-e^{x_i}\right)}{\left(\sum _{j=1}^n e^{x_j}\right){}^2}$

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks Bob!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind beeing slightly less symbolic and general but staying more standard you could proceed as follows.

Define

```
p[n_, i_] := Exp[x[i]]/Sum[Exp[x[j]], {j, 1, n}]
```

Now we have two typical cases for the derivative

```
With[{n = 5, i = 3, k = 2}, D[p[n, i], x[k]]]

(*
Out[97]= -(E^(x[2] + x[3])/(E^x[1] + E^x[2] + E^x[3] + E^x[4] + E^x[5])^2)
*)
```

and

```
With[{n = 5, i = 3, k = 3}, D[p[n, i], x[k]]]

(*
Out[98]= -(E^(2 x[3])/(E^x[1] + E^x[2] + E^x[3] + E^x[4] + E^x[5])^2) + E^x[3]/(
 E^x[1] + E^x[2] + E^x[3] + E^x[4] + E^x[5])
*)
```

From this the general pattern is easily gathered.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments from @It's Pronounced Oiler and following the link from @chris's answer, I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16390/5914) answer which was helpful.

First, instead of using subscripted symbols as variables, it is suggested to to use function call notation like this: `x[i]`. Second, the following code can be used to show Mathematica the intended relationship between `x[i]` and `x[j]`:

```
x /: D[x[i], x[j], NonConstants -> {x}] := KroneckerDelta[i,j]
```

The expression I want to differentiate then becomes:

```
p[i] = E^x[i] / Sum[E^x[j], {j,1,n}]
```

or,

$$
p_i = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_1^n e^{x_j}}
$$

And, the differentiation:

```
Assuming[i \[Element] Integers && j \[Element] Integers && 
  1 <= i <= n && 1 <= j <= n, D[p[i], x[i], NonConstants -> {x}]]
```

This produces the expected result of:

$$
\frac{e^{x_1} (-e^{x_i} + \sum_1^n e^{x_j})}{(\sum_1^n e^{x_j})^2}
$$

which reduces to,

$$
p_i - p_i^2
$$

Comment: Could somebody please explain how to get from the penultimate equation to the last one?