# Symbolic multivariable calculus with undetermined number of variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

$y$ is a function of $n$ independent variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ where $n$ is unknown. How do I calculate $\partial y/\partial x_k$ with Mathematica?

For example,

$$y=f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i x_i}$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_k}=a_k \textrm{ , } k=1,2,\dots,m$$

In Mathematica

```
y = Sum[a[i] x[i], {i, 1, n}]
```

But `D[y, x[k]]` won't return `a[k]` as I didn't tell Mathematica what `k` is.

How should I modify my code?

Comment: Have a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/how-to-differentiate-formally. Your question has already been posed

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Thanks! Now should I delete the question?

Comment: I am not one of the curators of this MSE. They will decide by themselves.