# Make Mathematica apply the same rule exhaustively in simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, rule

**Use Case**

Mathematica evaluate the partial derivative as:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{abc}}\sum _{j=1}^J \sum _{k=1}^K \log \left(\sum _{l=1}^L A_{jkl} B_{jkl}\right) = \sum _{j=1}^J \sum _{k=1}^K \frac{\sum _{l=1}^L\delta _{aj} \delta _{bk} \delta _{cl} B_{jkl}}{\sum _{l=1}^L A_{jkl}B_{jkl}}$$

Instead of

$$\frac{B_{abc}}{\sum _{l=1}^L A_{abl} B_{abl}}$$

For my case, each summation is over all possible values of an index.

The following code gives the result above:

```
expr = Sum[
   Log[Sum[A[j, k, l]*B[j, k, l], {l, 1, L}]], {j, 1, J}, {k, 1, K}];
expr = Simplify[D[expr, A[a, b, c]]]
```

**Current Solution**

In my [last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186377/simplify-sum-of-unnatural-conditional-functions-generated-by-derivative), Chris suggested the following rule to simplify the Kronecker deltas.

```
expr /. Sum[
    y_ KroneckerDelta[s_, r_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> (y /. s -> r) /.  
 Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[s_, r_] KroneckerDelta[s1_, r1_], {s_, 1, 
    p_}, {s1_, 1, p1_}] :> (y /. s -> r /. s1 -> r1)
```

**Potential Improvement**

However, the rule can be simpler if Mathematica can automatically apply [the following rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186406/simplify-rules-with-variable-number-of-arguments) for multiple times.

```
expr = expr /. Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}, z__] :> 
    Sum[(y /. s -> r), z] /. 
        Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> 
            (y /. s -> r)
```

**Question**

How to make Mathematica apply the same rule (or same set of rules) for simplification whenever possible?

Can I make a function call `SimplifyKroneckerDelta` that would apply this rule exhaustively?

Thanks.

---

Update:

Merely defining the following function leads to infinite loop.

```
SimplifyKronecker[expr_] = FixedPoint[expr /. Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}, z__] :> 
    Sum[(y /. s -> r), z] /. 
        Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> 
            (y /. s -> r), expr];
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `FixedPoint` for this?

Comment: Or use a while loop and define a procedure. While expression is same as old expression, apply rule and update old expression. Return expression. But I don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: Can use //. instead of /.

Answer (score 1):

Use `//.` to apply a list of rules exhaustively ([doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseARuleWithAnExpressionMoreThanOnce.html)).

```
SimplifyKroneckerSum[expr_] = expr //. {
    Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}, z__] :> 
        Sum[(y /. s -> r), z], 
    Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> 
        (y /. s -> r)};

expr = Sum[Log[Sum[A[j, k, l]*B[j, k, l], {l, 1, L}]], 
            {j, 1, J}, {k, 1, K}]

expr = Simplify[D[expr, A[a, b, c]]]

SimplifyKroneckerSum[expr]
```

Comment: The doc would be better if it has perma-link / anchor to each section / example.