# Simplify rules with variable number of arguments

Tags: simplifying-expressions, rule

**Problem**

How to simplify the following rules?

- The rules simplify (single, double, triple ...) summations of Kronecker delta.
- Replacement should occur if any summation and the Kronecker delta share an index.

**The rules**

Single summation:

```
expr /. Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s1_, 1, p1_}] :> (y /. s1 -> r)
```

Double summation:

```
expr /. Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s1_, 1, p1_}, {s2_, 1, p2_}] :> 
    Sum[(y /. s1 -> r), {s2, 1, p2}]
```

Tripple summation:

```
Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s1_, 1, p1_}, {s2_, 1, p2_}, {s3_, 1, p3_}] :> 
    Sum[(y /. s1 -> r), {s2, 1, p2}, {s3_, 1, p3_}]
```

**Test Case**

```
expr0 = Sum[Log[Sum[A[j, k, l]*B[j, k, l], {l, 1, L}]], 
            {j, 1, J}, {k, 1, K}]
expr = Simplify[D[expr0, A[a, b, c]]]
expr = expr /. Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> 
            (y /. s -> r)
expr = expr /. Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s1_, 1, p1_}, {s2_, 1, p2_}] :> 
            Sum[(y /. s1 -> r), {s2, 1, p2}]
expr = expr /. Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> 
            (y /. s -> r)
```

**Attempt**

I try to replace all the rules with the following rule:

```
Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}, z___] :> Sum[(y /. s -> r), z]
```

Doesn't work because sum needs at least 2 arguments but `z___` can match with nothing. In that case, `Sum[(y /. s -> r), z]` is a `Sum` with only 1 argument.

Answer (score 1):

Split the rule into two rules that match with summation over more than 1 index or just over 1 index.

`z__` matches with 1 or more arguments.

```
expr = expr /. Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}, z__] :> 
    Sum[(y /. s -> r), z] /. 
        Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> 
            (y /. s -> r)
```