# Defining a function that transforms an expression with rules

Tags: function-construction, rule

**Question**

I try to define a function that apply a set of rules to an expression in Mathematica 11.3.

However, the function returns a result that is not the same as directly applying the rule to the expression.

How to define the function correctly?

Thanks again.

**Expression**

```
expr2 = Sum[
  A[j, k, l, m]*KroneckerDelta[l, a]*KroneckerDelta[j, b]*
   KroneckerDelta[k, c], {j, 1, J}, {k, 1, K}, {l, 1, K}, {m, 1, K}]
```

**Transform with function**

```
SimplifyKronecker[
  x_] = x //. {Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], z1_, {s_, 1, p_}, 
      z2___] :> Sum[(y /. s -> r), z1, z2], 
    Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], z1___, {s_, 1, p_}, z2_] :> 
     Sum[(y /. s -> r), z1, z2], 
    Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> (y /. s -> r)}

SimplifyKronecker[expr2]
```

result: $\sum _{j=1}^J \sum _{k=1}^K \sum _{l=1}^K \sum _{m=1}^K \delta _{a,l} \delta
   _{b,j} \delta _{c,k} A(j,k,l,m)$

**Directly apply rule**

```
expr2 //. {Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], z1_, {s_, 1, p_}, 
      z2___] :> Sum[(y /. s -> r), z1, z2], 
    Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], z1___, {s_, 1, p_}, z2_] :> 
     Sum[(y /. s -> r), z1, z2], 
    Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> (y /. s -> r)}
```

result: $\sum _{m=1}^K A(b,c,a,m)$

Comment: Yo missed a colon in definition of the simplifying function: `SimplifyKronecker[
  x_] := x //. {Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], z1_, {s_, 1, p_}, 
      z2___] :> Sum[(y /. s -> r), z1, z2], 
    Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], z1___, {s_, 1, p_}, z2_] :> 
     Sum[(y /. s -> r), z1, z2], 
    Sum[y_ KroneckerDelta[r_, s_], {s_, 1, p_}] :> (y /. s -> r)}`

Comment: well, if you used a colon, you would get the desired result

Comment: because colon delays the evaluation. check here [Immediate and Delayed Definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html)

Comment: Defining a similar function for a similar set of rules work without `:=`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186409/61476 Since `:=` hurts performance, is it possible to avoid it here?

Comment: When you do not use the colon, `SimplifyKronecker[x]` simply returns `x` because it has already been evaluated. defining the function with a colon won't hurt performance in your case since without it function does nothing.