# Mathematica gravatar engine?

Tags: graphics

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13525/gravatars-identicons-with-mathematica/13526#13526) question asks about making gravatars in Mathematica, but the accepted answer is just a wrapper around the gravatar.com service.

Is there an open source Mathematica engine that performs the actual hash to graphics?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I don't know the exact details on how Gravatar generates identicons, the following might give you a something suitable.

Generally speaking, identicons are generated by hashing the user data and then creating a graphic based on the hash. A common technique is to cycle through and turn pixels on or off based on whether the value of a digit in the hash is even or odd.  Here the color is also based on the values in the hash, and also I imposed a certain kind of symmetry based on the hash as well. (I am quite sure this code can be made more aesthetically pleasing):

```
identiconPixels[id_String] := 
 Module[{hash, color, orient, cells, tm, q},
  hash = IntegerDigits[Hash[id, "MD5"], 8, 36];
  color = RGBColor[hash[[1 ;; 3]]/7];
  orient = If[OddQ[hash[[4]]], {Left, Bottom}, {Bottom, Left}];
  cells = 
   MapIndexed[If[OddQ[#1], color, White] &, Partition[hash, 6], {2}];
  q = Image[cells];
  Magnify[
   ImageAssemble[{{q, 
      ImageReflect[q, orient[[1]]]}, {ImageReflect[q, orient[[2]]], 
      ImageReflect[ImageReflect[q, Top], Left]}}], 4]
  ]
```

The `Magnification` here is to make the identicon larger to see the details.

```
identiconPixels["user@email.com"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
identiconPixels["user10@email.com"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same idea can generate avatars that are bit more visually interesting if instead of using pixels we use cells in a mesh:

```
identiconCells[id_String, size_] := 
 Module[{hash, color, orient, cells, tm, q},
  hash = IntegerDigits[Hash[id, "MD5"], 8, 36];
  color = RGBColor[hash[[1 ;; 3]]/7];
  orient = 
   If[OddQ[hash[[4]]], {ReflectionMatrix[{1, 0}], 
     ReflectionMatrix[{0, 1}]}, {RotationTransform[Pi/2], 
     RotationTransform[3 Pi/2]}];
  cells = MapIndexed[If[OddQ[#1], {2, #2[[1]]}, Nothing] &, hash];
  tm = TriangulateMesh[
    BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     Line[{1, 2, 3, 4, 1}]], MaxCellMeasure -> 1/26, 
    MeshQualityGoal -> 1];
  q = MeshPrimitives[tm, cells];
  Graphics[{color, EdgeForm[color], q, 
    Translate[GeometricTransformation[q, orient[[1]]], {2, 0}], 
    Translate[
     GeometricTransformation[q, RotationTransform[Pi]], {2, 0}], 
    Translate[GeometricTransformation[q, orient[[2]]], {0, 0}]}, 
   ImageSize -> size]
  ]
```

There is a bit of a 'magic' number with [`MaxCellMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html) which yields a square broken in 36 cells.

```
identiconCells["user@email.com",128]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
identiconCells["user6@email.com", 64]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Chuy, this is great thanks. Before accepting, two requests: 1, is there a way to avoid rasterizing in `identiconCells` - on my system the diagonals look ragged. 2 Can you explicitly parametrize identicon size?